# Проблема с выпадающим блоком

Tags: html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте. Возникла проблема: есть блок, он оформлен, как ссылка. При наведении на блок появляется снизу другой, в котором должна быть дополнительная информация о товаре. Проблема в том, что нижний блок так же выделяется, как ссылка и нельзя в этом блоке устанавливать необходимые значения.

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы внесли больше ясности в ваш вопрос, добавив пример кода и ознакомитесь со справкой [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). В данный момент на ваш вопрос сложно дать однозначный ответ.